Can we recite only Sri Venkatesha Prapatti daily?
Usually Sri Venkatesha Suprabhaatam, Venkatesha Stotram, Venkatesh Prapatti and Venkatesha Mangalaashaasanam are recited together traditionally.
Can we recite only Sri Venkatesha Prapatti daily?
Thank you.


tṛṇād api su-nīcena
taror api sahiṣṇunā
amāninā māna-dena
kīrtanīyaḥ sadā hariḥ

Translation: One can chant the Holy Name of the Lord in a humble state of mind, thinking himself lower than the straw in the street, more tolerant than the tree, devoid of all sense of false prestige, and ready to offer all respects to others. In such a state of mind one can chant the Holy Name of the Lord constantly.
There are no rules for glorifying the Supreme, other than doing it out of love.
